# Strange behavior - <li> menu item moving to next line in Internet Explorer, good on other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple ul/li navigation menu in my wordpress site. It looks good on Chrome, Firefox but when website opened in Internet Explorer, it behaves strangely and pushes the "Blog" menu item on next line where as it's fine and on same line on other browsers.

Link: http://construction.windoverdevelopment.xyz/construction/

I understand that this is not an upto mark question but please support with this issue - I haven't been able to resolve it. Thanks in advance

Screenshot 1: (in Chrome - whole menu in same line)

[image]

Screenshot 2: (in IE - BLOG is moved on next line) 
[image: BLOG is moved on next line]

The css for navigation is:

```
.main-navigation {
    background: rgba(0, 70, 127, 0.95);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 17px 14px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 17px 14px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0 17px 14px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    /*

border-top: 2px solid #fff;

border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;

*/
}
.main-navigation li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.main-navigation li:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 95px;
    right: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
#menu-main-menu>li.menu-item:last-child>a {
    color: #00447C;
    font-family:"Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.main-navigation li ul li {
    padding: 0;
}
.main-navigation li ul li:last-child {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.main-navigation li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 35px;
}
```

Comment: Have you started with a CSS reset?  Very helpful in rendering issues like this.

Comment: Yes, reset.css is included

Comment: I didn't see one in the source.. what reset are you using?

Comment: The import on top @import url(../twentytwelve/style.css); has reset.css actually

Comment: I see it now buried in there, is that one that came with the template?  Just wondering who created it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think sum of child controllers width exceeds the parent div container width. You can optimize padding value for IE browser. But better way is that remove the rule that works different in IE and Chrome.

In style.css; (line: 535)

```
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu, .main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul {
     font-family: "adrianna-condensed-demibold",sans-serif;
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: 600;
     border: none;
     display: none;
     padding: 3px 0 2px;
     text-align: center; /*This one is problematic*/
     width: 100%;
}
```

`text-align: center;` rule works different in IE and Chrome you can adjust this rule.

Comment: Okay, but how do you suggest to handle this `text-align: center` for IE ?

Comment: First of all if you have noticed first <li> controller has more padding in IE than Chrome. text-align:center will fix it. Then you can adjust the padding value. (In this case you need to set 34px for padding rule)

Comment: There must be a silent difference in font. I checked now in Chrome, width of tag which represents BLOG controller is 40.516 and in IE width of <a> tag which represents BLOG is 41.129. You can balance the difference by using padding attribute.(reduce 1 px)

Answer (score 0):

The rule:

```
/*media all*/
.main-navigation li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 35px;
}
```

looks to be causing your issue, adjust the right padding for that last element.

A css reset would likely have helped to resolve this, but it can be a PITA to deal with adding one late in the game.

Comment: But if the right padding is problem, why doesn't it observes same behavior in Chrome ?

Comment: I understand that a quick fix can be to change 35px to 25px for right padding. But still, i don't get why it's problematic in IE only ?

Comment: It very well may be as simple as how each renders a font.  I've noticed major and subtle differences in browsers rendering different fonts.  This could be minor differences in letter spacing, weight, etc. which could be a factor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this only for IE, for specific version use some CSS hack.

```
.main-navigation li > a {

  padding-right: 34px;

}
```